# Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug' - Gradle dependencies?

Tags: android, android-studio

I didn't want to start a new question related to this issue since I know there are a few already, but I still haven't found a solution and I'm pretty stuck.

I am currently getting the error:

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

And this is what the Gradle Console is showi

> > UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lbolts/AggregateException;  at
> >     com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:579)
> >       at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:535)
> >       at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:517)
> >       at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:164)    at
> >     com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:188)  at
> >     com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:504)
> >       at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:334)  at
> >     com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)  at
> >     com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)     at
> >     com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
>
> FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>
>   > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>   >     org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
>   >     '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java''
>   >     finished with non-zero exit value 2
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>
> BUILD FAILED

This is my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.andrewnwalker.mousetimes_california"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['Parse-*.jar'])
    compile files('libs/Parse-1.12.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/bolts-tasks-1.3.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.5.jar')
    compile files('libs/joda-time-2.9.1.jar')
}
```

I've tried all of the obvious things such as cleaning, rebuilding, opening/closing. I've also tried removing some of the dependencies to see if that would make a difference.

As far as I know I didn't change anything from when it worked fine. I'm pretty sure I just ran the project for a second time in a row and the error appeared. I might be wrong though.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Recently, I encountered the same problem and here is my solution with 2 steps:

1. Top level Gradle:

   ```
   // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
   buildscript {
   repositories {
       jcenter()
   }
   dependencies {
       classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha3'
       classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-alpha3'//for any google libs
      }
    }

   allprojects {
   repositories {
         jcenter()
       }
   }
   ```
2. Module(app) level Gradle:

   ```
   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

   android {
   compileSdkVersion 23
   buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"


   defaultConfig {
       applicationId "your_app_id"
       minSdkVersion 9
       targetSdkVersion 22
       // Enabling multidex support can also help (uncomment and test)
       //multiDexEnabled true
   }

   buildTypes {
       release {
           //minifyEnabled true
           //shrinkResources true
           proguardFiles 'proguard-project.txt'
       }
   }

   } 

   dependencies {
   //your dependencies
   }
   apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' **//Place this line at the end if you use any google service lib.**
   ```

Comment: I gave you're suggestions a try (some of which I had already tried), and unfortunately it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Update your top level gradle like this,

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-alpha3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Update your app level gradle like this,

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        // package name, target sdk and version code as per your code
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        incremental true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    // your libraries here
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And update your android manifest file like this,

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

And add this line to your launcher activity in onCreate function.

```
MultiDex.install(this);
```

See if this works.