# org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Due to `65K` error in my project I need it to migrate to Android Studio . While running

> ./gradlew assembleDebug

I am getting the error:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: 
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: 
org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: 
Process 'command '/opt/jdk/jdk1.8.0_45/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

I know this is very common error which all get while migrating an Eclipse project to Android Studio.

**I have tried:**

[Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug' - Gradle dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34834097/execution-failed-for-task-apptransformclasseswithdexfordebug-gradle-depend)

[Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug' while implementing Google sign in for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33369163/execution-failed-for-task-apptransformclasseswithdexfordebug-while-implement)

[Android Studio TransformException : Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33915955/android-studio-transformexception-errorexecution-failed-for-task-apptransf)

[Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33717886/errorexecution-failed-for-task-apptransformclasseswithdexfordebug)

[com.android.build.transform.api.TransformException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32807587/com-android-build-transform-api-transformexception)

https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded/issues/110

I tried every solution, I tried to add `.jar` files one by one in my project, I used only those Google-services packages which are getting used in my project, I even added `multidex` jar.But nothing helps me

**My Build.gradle file:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.petzview.android"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }

    dexOptions {
        incremental = true;
        maxProcessCount 4
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        dexInProcess = false
        preDexLibraries = false
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.0'
    compile project(':AVIOCtrlDefine')
    compile project(':Facebook')
    compile project(':SlidingMenu-master')
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
android.packagingOptions {
    exclude 'the META-INF / DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
    exclude 'the META-INF / LICENSE'
    exclude 'the META-INF / LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'the META-INF / license.txt'
    exclude 'the META-INF / NOTICE'
    exclude 'the META-INF / the NOTICE.txt '
    exclude ' the META-INF / NOTICE.txt '
    exclude ' the META-INF / ASL2.0 '
    exclude ' the META-INF / Services / javax.annotation.processing.Processor '
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**My main gradle file:**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
       classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
       classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

**Screenshot of my libs folder:**

[image]

**MyApplication.java:**

```
public class MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication {
    private Object mTempObject = null;

    private boolean flagHomeFragmentFirstCreate = true;

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    }
```

**My Manifest class containing MyApplication:**

```
 <application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

After running

> ./gradlew assembleDebug --stacktrace

**Error Log**

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:52)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:203)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:185)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:66)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:50)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:25)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:110)
at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
         org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$4.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:154)
at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:52)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:151)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:32)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:99)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:93)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:62)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:93)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:82)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:94)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:78)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:48)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:51)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:43)
at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:170)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:237)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:210)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:206)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:54)
at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:30)
at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:129)
at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException:
com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
 '/opt/jdk/jdk1.8.0_45/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
at com.android.builder.profile.Recorder$Block.handleException(Recorder.java:54)
at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder$1.record(ThreadRecorder.java:57)
at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder$1.record(ThreadRecorder.java:47)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:173)
at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:244)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:220)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:231)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:209)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
         ... 60 more Caused by: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
 '/opt/jdk/jdk1.8.0_45/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexTransform.transform(DexTransform.java:421)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$3.call(TransformTask.java:178)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$3.call(TransformTask.java:174)
at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder$1.record(ThreadRecorder.java:55)
         ... 69 more Caused by: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
 '/opt/jdk/jdk1.8.0_45/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.dexOutOfProcess(AndroidBuilder.java:1553)
at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.runDexer(AndroidBuilder.java:1495)
at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.convertByteCode(AndroidBuilder.java:1482)
 at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexTransform.transform(DexTransform.java:251)
         ... 72 more Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
 '/opt/jdk/jdk1.8.0_45/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.dexOutOfProcess(AndroidBuilder.java:1549)
        ... 75 more Caused by: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
 '/opt/jdk/jdk1.8.0_45/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.assertNormalExitValue(GradleProcessResult.java:43)
at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder$3.call(AndroidBuilder.java:1538)
at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder$3.call(AndroidBuilder.java:1531)
Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
 '/opt/jdk/jdk1.8.0_45/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle$ExecResultImpl.assertNormalExitValue(DefaultExecHandle.java:367)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.assertNormalExitValue(GradleProcessResult.java:41)
         ... 2 more
```

**Error while running application on device:**

> Error:trouble processing "java/awt/font/NumericShaper.class":
>   Error:Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or
>   javax.*) Error:when not building a core library. Error:This is often
>   due to inadvertently including a core library file Error:in your
>   application's project, when using an IDE (such as Error:Eclipse). If
>   you are sure you're not intentionally defining a Error:core class,
>   then this is the most likely explanation of what's Error:going on.
>   Error:However, you might actually be trying to define a class in a
>   core Error:namespace, the source of which you may have taken, for
>   example, Error:from a non-Android virtual machine project. This will
>   most Error:assuredly not work. At a minimum, it jeopardizes the
>   Error:compatibility of your app with future versions of the platform.
>   Error:It is also often of questionable legality. Error:If you really
>   intend to build a core library -- which is only Error:appropriate as
>   part of creating a full virtual machine Error:distribution, as opposed
>   to compiling an application -- then use Error:the "--core-library"
>   option to suppress this error message. Error:If you go ahead and use
>   "--core-library" but are in fact Error:building an application, then
>   be forewarned that your application Error:will still fail to build or
>   run, at some point. Please be Error:prepared for angry customers who
>   find, for example, that your Error:application ceases to function once
>   they upgrade their operating Error:system. You will be to blame for
>   this problem. Error:If you are legitimately using some code that
>   happens to be in a Error:core package, then the easiest safe
>   alternative you have is to Error:repackage that code. That is, move
>   the classes in question into Error:your own package namespace. This
>   means that they will never be in Error:conflict with core system
>   classes. JarJar is a tool that may help Error:you in this endeavor. If
>   you find that you cannot do this, then Error:that is an indication
>   that the path you are on will ultimately Error:lead to pain,
>   suffering, grief, and lamentation. Error:1 error; aborting
>   Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>
> > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
> >     java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
> >     com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
> >     org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
> >     '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit
> >     value 1 Information:BUILD FAILED

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Try changing `minifyEnabled true`

Comment: Thanks for your time , but still getting same error

Comment: Do you need all these google libraries?? My suggestion is if you don't need any one of them the remove it. Sync the project, Clean it and Build again.

Comment: Two were extra (i updated that in my above gradle file) , that i removed , rest all are needed , so after removing that i sync the project and rebuild it even i try invalidate cache and restart ..but still getting same problem :(

Comment: I think the problem is in your import..!! you imported eclipse project right??

Comment: yes , this project was originally built in eclipse , i migrated it to studio as i mentioned above in explanation of my problem

Comment: Try this for importing : http://stackoverflow.com/a/36689610/6127411. and try again to build..!!

Comment: okay , so what i done is , i just close the project and select the same project again using Android studio userInterface (Import Project (Eclipse ADT,Gradle etc)).Is this what you trying to say ?

Comment: still getting same error..no luck!!

Comment: Try creating new project then..!!

Comment: I just created the new project and put all my files in it but still getting same error .

Comment: Please check your XML layouts, I was facing a similar problem and it was due to issues in XML.

Comment: I solved my problem with the post below: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52645163/lombok-1-18-2-throws-transformclasseswithdexbuilderfordebug

Answer (score 30):

Check `build.gradle`(Module: Android) fixed problem for me.

Modify it to workable version.

```
android {
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'
}
```

Comment: this tools help me to find missing libs. Thx u!

Comment: mine was buildToolsVersion = "30.0.2" when i set it to  buildToolsVersion='23.0.1'  spent 2 days on this thanks!

Answer (score 24):

Just a simple solution is here...it worked for me:

1. Clean Project
2. Rebuild project
3. Sync project with gradle file

Comment: Worked. Didn't need to sync project though.

Comment: These kinds of clean/rebuilt solution never worked for me.

Comment: Worked also for me, even without synch! I was getting this error after having updated the emulator and downloaded a device image...

Comment: @CopsOnRoad gradle itself never worked for me. Gradle is broken by nature. Gradle is impossible to use without errors

Answer (score 19):

the steps I followed are:

1. close `Android Studio` *(or `IntelliJ IDEA`)*
2. in your project's directory:

   1. delete `.idea` directory
   2. delete `.gradle` directory
   3. delete all `.iml` files

      - `find . | grep -e .iml$ | xargs rm`
3. use `Android Studio` to re-open the directory as a project

Terminal commands:

```sh
# close Android Studio
cd "your project's directory"
rm -rf ./.idea
rm -rf ./.gradle
find . | grep -e .iml$ | xargs rm
# use Android Studio to re-open the directory as a project
```

Comment: `find . -type f -name '*.iml'` works better than `grep`

Answer (score 12):

I had the same issue and I could solve it like this:

1) **If your `minSdkVersion` is set to 21 or a higher value**, the only thing you need to do is to set `multiDexEnabled` in your `build.gradle` file at the module level, as shown below:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 21 
        targetSdkVersion 28
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}
```

2) However, **if your minSdkVersion is set to 20 or less**, you should use the MultiDex compatibility library, as follows:

2.1) Modify the module-level `build.gradle` file to enable MultiDex and add the MultiDex library as dependency, as shown below

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 15 
        targetSdkVersion 28
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
  implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

2.2) According to the `Application` class or not, do one of the following actions:

2.2.1) If you do not cancel the `Application` class, modify your manifest file to set `android: name` in the `<application>` tag as shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapp">
    <application
            android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" >
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

2.2.2) If you cancel the `Application` class, you must change it to extend `MultiDexApplication` (if possible) as shown below:

```
public class MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication { ... }
```

2.2.3) Also, if you override the `Application` class and can not change the base class, alternatively you can override the `attachBaseContext ()` method and invoke `MultiDex.install (this)` to enable MultiDex:

```
public class MyApplication extends SomeOtherApplication {
  @Override
  protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
     super.attachBaseContext(base);
     MultiDex.install(this);
  }
}
```

[Please use this link, it was really useful for me!](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex)

Comment: in my case there was compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1" in gradle. I removed it and added its parts. Otherwise it s too heavy .

Answer (score 4):

Try to move:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

just below:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

In your module Gradle file, then make sure all Google service's have the version `9.0.0`.

Make sure that only this build tools is used:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
```

Make sure in gradle-wrapper.properties:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip
```

After all above is correct, then make menu File -> Invalidate caches and restart.

Comment: Thanks stepan for your reply but on putting just below the com.android.application , produces errors as mentioned in link :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34370603/version-conflict-updating-to-8-4-0

Comment: Hey,Stepan , i tried this but its not working giving me same error

Comment: applicationId "com.example.android" -> applicationId "com.petzview.android.commons"

Comment: i just changed it while adding question here , the real applicationId is "com.petzview.android" , let me change that in question too inorder to remove confusion

Answer (score 3):

I have been struggling with this problem for 2 days. And tried all options. 
Finally noticed that after updating my android studio, it was not showing me the compile errors like @v.d. wrote above. My problem was, In my build files, I was using compile(which should be replaced with **implementation** or **api**) and **testcompile**(which also replaced by **testimplementation**). Notice that I have changed in whole build files(android, app and others - in my case I also had folding-cell library)

**for example instead of this**

```
compile project(path: ':folding-cell')
```

**write this**

```
implementation project(path: ':folding-cell')
```

Answer (score 2):

Its Just Simple the Compiler **Did not accept the last changes you've made** so go to the last file that you've made a change It will show the error just change it and recompile.

Answer (score 2):

delete intermediates folder from app\build\intermediates.
 then rebuild the project. it will work

Answer (score 2):

```
        If you are updating your build.gradle(app) with latest version and third party library include in project that's why you need to update your library with latest version in same file. 

In my case i've to update my dependency with below version code.
    
    dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'
            classpath 'org.greenrobot:greendao-gradle-plugin:3.3.0'
            } 

It should look like this:
        
            dependencies {
                classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.0'
                classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'
                classpath 'org.greenrobot:greendao-gradle-plugin:3.3.1'
            }
```

Comment: https://github.com/greenrobot/greenDAO/issues/1110#issuecomment-1609217601

Answer (score 1):

your manifest application name should contain application class name.
Like

```
<application
        android:name="your package name.MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Comment: it's inside commons folder

Comment: i just put MyApplication.java class under main package and removed it from commons folder , but on running ./gradlew assembleDebug i am getting same error

Comment: just extend Application rather than MultiDexApplication, i think it will solve your problem.

Comment: can you confirm your Application class getting called by using log or by debugging

Comment: i remove multidexApplication and extend the Application but still same error

Comment: witch device you are using for testing? please put debugger point at MyApplication class and check whether debugger point is getting hit.

Comment: sorry , i am not able to launch the application then how can i debug it

Comment: can you tell me which version of os your device contain means is it prelollipop device?

Comment: its marshmallow 6.0

Comment: in my case using android studio 2.0 preview 4 I suddenly got that problem and adding multiDexEnabled true didn't help, and also clean and rebuilt didn't help.

so the only thing that solved it for me is deleting that file:

YOUR_APP_NAME\app\build\intermediates
and run the application and it works. have you tried this?

Comment: yes , i already tried it , but in my case its also not working , while running i am getting one error Error:trouble processing "java/awt/font/NumericShaper.class":
Error:Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*), Have you ever faced it ?

Comment: please give your whole build.gradle screenshots.Above screenshots half of your build.gradle file is visible

Comment: its already on top below the links i have provided , please check

Comment: dude can you please give a try with latest buildToolsVersion "X.Y.Z". latest tool version is 23.0.3 (buildToolsVersion "23.0.3".).if you don't have it please download it.

Answer (score 1):

for me it was just a little compile error and sadly Android Studio doesn't show it . please search manually .
trying to enable work offline and clean&rebuild may help you more

Answer (score 1):

Just remove this line from build.gradle(Project folder)

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Now rebuild the application. works fine
Happy coding

Answer (score 1):

**Apply in ProGuard-rules**

```
-ignorewarnings
```

Answer (score 1):

My Simple Answer is and only solution...

Please Check The layout files, which you added lastly there MUST be a error in the .xml file for sure.

We may simply copy and pasting .xml file from other project and something missing in the xml file..

Error in the .xml file would be some of the below....

1. Something missing in Drawable folder or String.xml Or Dimen.xml...

After Placing all the available code in the respected folders do not forget to CLEAN The Project...

Answer (score 1):

I have disabled Instant Run feature from the preferences and the issue was solved.

Answer (score 1):

Invalidate Caches works for me

Answer (score 0):

For me the only thing that works is to add to repositories

```
maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
```

It should look like this:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
```

Comment: I had this but the problem exists.

Answer (score 0):

For my case, I follow the steps from `Firebase` and by mistake I pated it in a wrong file.

Then, I returned to the project from `Project` to `Android`. Once in the `Android view` I pasted the file `/projectname/app/YOUR-FILE-HERE` and now, you have to compile again.

Answer (score 0):

you just change import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
to 
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

and extends AppCompatActivity

Answer (score 0):

Well in my case i was accessing an static array of a class by reference of that class, but as we know we can directly access static member via class name. So when I replaced reference with class name where I was accessing that array. It fixed this error.

Answer (score 0):

Add `multiDexEnabled true` to your app-level Gradle, like this:

```
defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Migrate to androidX library**

With Android Studio 3.2 and higher, you can migrate an existing project to AndroidX by selecting `Refactor > Migrate` to AndroidX from the menu bar.

Source:
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

Answer (score 0):

clear project and then run. it will work

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is facing a **similar type of error** while adding **ShimmerRecyclerView** Loader, make sure to add: `maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }` **under allprojects** in your app-level Gradle, like below:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        // Add it here
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I am also facing this types of error while run the project in Android Studio. It may be facing this types of error due to **dependencies** need to be upgrade with higher evrsion.

I have used below dependencies

> implementation 'jp.wasabeef:glide-transformations:3.3.0'

Now changed with upgraded version as below

> implementation 'jp.wasabeef:glide-transformations:4.3.0'

Now sync the **build.gradle** then run the app is successfully.

Answer (score 0):

for me, it was the missing Manifest file that was to blame. I created a new module and forgot to add Manifest

Answer (score 0):

Just update your libraries in build.gradle(Project folder)
and try again

Answer (score -1):

first you remove this thing in your project  .. its is in build.gradle(module:app)  then build your app now you project show the actual error and you find what is your actual problem is .. and after you find actual problem again paste it where its is belong to

allprojects {  gradle.projectsEvaluated {

```
    tasks.withType(JavaCompile)
```

{
            options.encoding = 'UTF-8'

```
        options.compilerArgs
```

<< "-Xlint:unchecked" << "-Xlint:deprecation"}]}}