# Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac' Android Studio 3.1 Update

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-studio-3.1

I am getting error after updating the version of **Android Studio 3.1 Canary 6**

I don't why its happen, before that it's running successfully.

```
org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkJavaCompiler.execute(JdkJavaCompiler.java:50)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkJavaCompiler.execute(JdkJavaCompiler.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.delegateAndHandleErrors(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:98)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.execute(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.execute(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:37)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.execute(CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.execute(CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.java:25)
    at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.performCompilation(JavaCompile.java:207)
    at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.compile(JavaCompile.java:192)
    at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.compile(JavaCompile.java:124)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.factory.AndroidJavaCompile.compile(AndroidJavaCompile.java:125)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:121)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:60)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:97)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:87)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:626)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:581)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:59)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:128)
    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:46)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$ExecuteTasks.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:314)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.runTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:204)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:134)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.executeTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:109)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.call(GradleBuildController.java:78)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.call(GradleBuildController.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:152)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:100)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:75)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.run(ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:62)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$1.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:40)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:51)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:47)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:39)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:32)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:69)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:45)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:62)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:82)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:295)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The Main Error is:

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
```

My Gradle file is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.demo"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.6.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.dlazaro66.qrcodereaderview:qrcodereaderview:2.0.3'
    compile 'com.github.elevenetc:badgeview:v1.0.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.elevenetc:badgeview:v1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
}
```

Is there any solution?

Comment: Did you update the class path to this classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0-alpha06'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37583875/org-gradle-api-tasks-taskexecutionexception-execution-failed-for-task-apptra)

Comment: @RakshitNawani Yes, I have updated that path.

Comment: @Sree Its not duplicate dude, otherwise i won't put question.

Comment: @PratikButani : What about the Gradle version in the wrapper did you update that too?

Comment: Yes, `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0-alpha06'`

Comment: @PratikButani try with `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha5'`

Comment: this may be an issue with `annotationProcessor 'com.github.elevenetc:badgeview:v1.0.0'`. can you able to change it to `compile 'com.github.elevenetc:badgeview:v1.0.0'`

Comment: if this help please let me know, I can write an answer with some more details.

Comment: Its also not working, I got error like. `Annotation processors must be explicitly declared now.  The following dependencies on the compile classpath are found to contain annotation processor.  Please add them to the annotationProcessor configuration.
  - butterknife-7.0.1.jar (com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1)`

Comment: Simply update butter knife with Annotation processor too

`compile 'com.github.elevenetc:badgeview:v1.0.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.elevenetc:badgeview:v1.0.0'` may work

Comment: Check if any Class has *import missing* . In my case, an Activity was not imported for Intent. When imported and rebuild, it worked.

Answer (score 181, accepted):

- My solution is simple, don't look at the error notification in **Build - Run tasks** (which should be Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac')
- Just fix all errors in the **Java Compiler** section below it.

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. I already wasted 4 to 5 hours to solve the error.
you tricks work

Comment: I don't have any errors in the Java Compiler section. What should I do?

Comment: run into a lot of errors after migration to AndroidX. I had to go and fix all the import lines, ie switches them from old v4 to new androidx. One would think migration would do it, wrong, it would not.

Answer (score 29):

I had similar issue and no errors shown in Compilation. I have tried to clean and rebuild without any success. I managed to find the issue by using **Invalidate Caches/Restart** from file Menu, after the restart I managed to see the compilation error.

[image]

Answer (score 12):

I'm on 
Android Studio 3.1
Build #AI-173.4670197, built on March 22, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b02 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.

I had the same issue and it only worked after changing my build.grade file to

```
    compileOptions {                                                          
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8 
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8


}
```

Prior to this change nothing worked and all compiles would fail. previously my settings were

```
sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7 
targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
```

Answer (score 7):

I found the solution as Its problem with **Android Studio 3.1 Canary 6**

My backup of **Android Studio 3.1 Canary 5** is useful to me and saved my half day.

Now My **build.gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.demo"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    implementation "com.android.support:design:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0"
    implementation "com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2"
    implementation "com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0"
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.6.0"
    implementation "com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2"
    implementation "com.dlazaro66.qrcodereaderview:qrcodereaderview:2.0.3"
    compile 'com.github.elevenetc:badgeview:v1.0.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.elevenetc:badgeview:v1.0.0'
    testImplementation "junit:junit:4.12"
    androidTestImplementation("com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1", {
        exclude group: "com.android.support", module: "support-annotations"
    })
}
```

and My **gradle** is:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0-alpha06'
```

and its working finally.

I think there problem in **Android Studio 3.1 Canary 6**

Thank you all for your time.

Comment: I think you meant "My backup of Android Studio 3.1 **Canary 5** is useful to me" (i.e. Canary 5, not 6).

Comment: Yeah, My Mistake. Thanks.

Comment: i have the same problem after adding payumoney dependency

Comment: I am using stable version not Canary. I got this issue.

Answer (score 4):

I solved it by deleting **"/.idea/libraries"** from project. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try updating your `buildToolVersion` to `27.0.2` instead of `27.0.3`

The error probably occurring because of compatibility issue with build tools

Comment: add     
repositories {
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
} inside android {
...
} and delete annotationProcessor 'com.github.elevenetc:badgeview:v1.0.0'

this change is to be done in app.grale file


below are the changes

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this solution works for you or not but just want to heads you up on compiler and build tools version compatibility issues.

This could be because of Java and Gradle version mismatch.

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip
```

Gradle 4.4 is compatible with only Java 7 and 8. So, point your global variable JAVA_HOME to Java 7 or 8.

In mac, add below line to your ***~/.bash_profile***

`export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_191.jdk/Contents/Home`

You can have multiple java versions. Just change the JAVA_HOME path based on need. You can do it easily, [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26252993/1897654)

Answer (score 2):

Just solve the problem which come from java compiler instead of Build-Run task

Answer (score 1):

Go to preferences(settings) : click on Build,Execution,Deployment .....then select : Instant Run ......and uncheck its topmost checkbox (i.e Disable Instant Run)

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me!

App/build.gradle

//Add this....Keep both version same

```
compileOptions {                                                          
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8 
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We just need to check that your gradle-wrapper version and build_tools version should be compatible and your machine gradle should be compatible to gradle wrapper version.

We have 6.5 gradle wrapper version

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-bin.zip
```

in project level build.gradle

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'
```

Open terminal and check gradle version using command

```
gradle --version 

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 6.5
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2020-06-02 20:46:21 UTC
```

After all these just invalidate cache and restart

Comment: this solves my problem, Thanks. combination of 6.5 and 4.0.1

Answer (score 0):

This problem is commonly related to compiler errors in the Java code. Sometimes Android Studio does not show these errors in the `Project explorer`. However, when a problematic `.java` file is opened, errors are shown. Try to resolve errors and rebuild the project.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue after selecting the "Target Compatibility" to 1.8 Java version. File -> Project Structure -> Modules.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I could solve it by switching fom JDK 11 to JDK 8.