# FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. * What went wrong: Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: flutter, dart

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:.
> Required by:
> project :app

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 45s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 1):

I am not really sure but try to :

- Set your java SDK location in project settings
- upgrade your `buildToolsVersion` in your `build.gradle` file. See which version is the latest and set it to that.

If neither of these methods work , save your project in a repository and re-download android studio if it comes to that.

You can even visit this thread and see if any of the methods solve your problem : [Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac' Android Studio 3.1 Update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48071618/execution-failed-for-task-appcompiledebugjavawithjavac-android-studio-3-1-up/52056367)