# Failed to resolve: runtime in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

After Gradle build getting Failed to resolve : runtime in android Studio even not using/added any architecture related component.

(incomplete) logcat:

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100) at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
```

Comment: post your logcat log.

Comment: org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
 at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37583875/org-gradle-api-tasks-taskexecutionexception-execution-failed-for-task-apptra
refer this may help to you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gradle build tool cannot find play-services-tasks.aar? Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50562212/gradle-build-tool-cannot-find-play-services-tasks-aar-why)

Comment: Thank@Floern it works

Answer (score 0):

I Added `maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }` as first entry in a`llprojects/repositories` in top level `build.gradle`

**such as this:**

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        google()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        jcenter()
    }
}
```