# what happened jar (library ) compile version is different with app compile version?

Tags: android

For example
android jar library is compiled with
compile sdk version : 20
target sdk version : 20

And my app 
compile sdk version : 21
and target sdk version :21

what happen my app use this jar library.
can it be compiled and executed in android api 21 os?

Answer (score 0):

i have faced this kind of problem once (and there are many question's on SOF) which arise due to difference in version of the lib/*.jar file uses and there project is using, and the build failed because on task was getting failed.

> `org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug'.`

I am not saying you will get this error for sure but there is a high risk of gradle build failure if the dispute happen's.

Reference:

1. [Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54122344/exception-after-added-external-libraries-to-android-project/54122592)
2. [Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35890257/android-errorexecution-failed-for-task-apptransformclasseswithdexforrelease/35899240)