# Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForRelease'. for ionic 3 build --release

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, ionic3

Ionic cordova build android successfully but with --release failed

i try cordova clean 
Change cordova platform version

apply app/build.gradle

android {
    defaultConfig {

```
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 28 
    multiDexEnabled true
```

}
}

$ ionic info
cli packages: (C:\Users\AMIT-PC\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.0
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.0
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.4
Cordova Platforms  : android 8.0.0
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.1.1
```

System:

```
Android SDK Tools : 25.2.5
Node              : v8.9.4
npm               : 5.6.0
OS                : Windows 10
```

Environment Variables:

```
ANDROID_HOME : F:\Android\android-sdk
```

Misc:

```
backend : pro
```

$ ionic cordova requirements

> cordova requirements

Requirements check results for android:

Java JDK: installed 1.8.0
Android SDK: installed true
Android target: installed android-29,android-Q,android-28,android-27,android-26,android-25
Gradle: installed F:\Android\gradle-5.5\bin\gradle

### $ ionic cordova build android

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
 in 3s
42 actionable tasks: 42 up-to-date
Built the following apk(s):
        F:\trans4mrz\platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk

### $ Ionic cordova build android --release

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForRelease'.

  > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives:
  >   Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
  >   Program type already present: org.apache.cordova.BuildHelper
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s
[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova build android --release (exit code 1).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37583875/org-gradle-api-tasks-taskexecutionexception-execution-failed-for-task-apptra)

Comment: Thank you for Reply  With ionic cordova build android --debug successfully Build . But when i try to build with release the above error show

Comment: @Unnati Mistry I have this exact same issue with --release not working.  Did you find a soultion yet?